# ctypes - function only returns empty string

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm having problems with using ctypes to invoke a function from a C++ library (wrapped with extern C) that is supposed to return a string. I'm pretty sure I've got my argtypes and restype set up correctly for the ctypes interface into a function that is supposed to return a string, but no matter what I only get an empty string as the returned result.

C++ Code:

```
const char* disasmC_PEProgram_getSections(PEProgram *p) {
    return p->getSections().c_str();
}
```

Python Code:

```
lib.disasmC_PEProgram_getSections.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
lib.disasmC_PEProgram_getSections.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
resultStr = lib.disasmC_PEProgram_getSections(self.peProgram_p)

# Displays empty string for resultStr!
print "Result: %s" % (resultStr,)
```

Comment: print Result: %s" % (resultStr.value)?

Comment: `resultStr` is supposed to be a python string as marshalled from `char*` by `ctypes`. It's not an object with a `.value` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the value returned from `disasmC_PEProgram_getSections()` is a local variable or contains nulls or something.  Provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want more specific help.

Here's my MCVE that shows your Python code is correct.  Note my C++ code returns a reference to the string in the object, to make sure the lifetime of the string lasts until the object is destroyed.

**test.cpp**

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define API __declspec(dllexport) // Windows-specific export

class PEProgram
{
    string section;
public:
    PEProgram() : section("section") {}
    const string& getSections() const { return section; }
};

extern "C" {
    API PEProgram* PEProgram_new() { return new PEProgram(); }
    API void PEProgram_delete(PEProgram* p) { delete p; }
    API const char* disasmC_PEProgram_getSections(PEProgram *p) {
        return p->getSections().c_str();
    }
}
```

**test.py**

```
#!python36
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('test')
lib.PEProgram_new.argtypes = None
lib.PEProgram_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
lib.PEProgram_delete.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
lib.PEProgram_delete.restype = None

p = lib.PEProgram_new()

lib.disasmC_PEProgram_getSections.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
lib.disasmC_PEProgram_getSections.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
resultStr = lib.disasmC_PEProgram_getSections(p)

# Displays empty string for resultStr!
print(f'Result: {resultStr}')

lib.PEProgram_delete(p)
```

**Output**

```
Result: b'section'
```

Note that if my class is:

```
class PEProgram
{
public:
    string getSections() const { return "section"; }
};
```

Then I get `b''` as the value in Python.  That's because the string returned by `disasmC_PEProgram_getSections` is now a temporary value that gets destroyed after the function `disasmC_PEProgram_getSections` returns.  The `const char*` returned now points to freed memory, and undefined behavior occurs.

Comment: My function signature and yours match and I also hardcoded the string like you, but I'm also getting an empty string.

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) const char* tryStr(const char* key){
        std::string keyStr = "FREAKING";
        return keyStr.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Do u mind explain what's the concept behind this "temporary value that gets destroyed"? And how can I fix that?

Comment: @beast In your comment code, `keyStr` is a local variable that is destroyed when the function exits. Make it static or global, for example, and and it won’t get released.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I'm not a C programmer but have to extend my colleague's codes. I figured the way to avoid this is to use `malloc`

Comment: @Beast As long as you have a way to free it when you are done that works.

Comment: May I know if there's another way? Idk how to free it since my function **returns** a ptr to a char array into the Python realm